# Invalid Cast Exception, Unable to Cast COM object to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

Similar questions have been asked before, but I want to try and refine it to my situation.

I am downloading a legacy file type (Excel 2003 (.xls)) and I need to strip the data from the file. The problem is I get :

```
 {"Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' 
to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed
because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
```

I am currently trying to get this working on my machine before I send the app to production, which will/does have excel on the server.

I have tried reinstalling office, but that did not work. I think the problem lies more in the fact that I have office 2013 on my box and I am attempting to run a decade old file type through it.

I tried to use this:

```
 public void Convert(String file)
    {
        var app = new Application();
        var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file);
        wb.SaveAs(file + "x", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
        wb.Close();
        app.Quit();
    }
```

That still causes the same problem, because the file will not open.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Here is the full method I am using

```
public Worksheet GetExcelBy(string url)
    {
        var fileName = @"C:\temp\tempfile.xls";
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
        Convert(fileName);
        var excel = new Application();
        var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        return (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["Data 6"];
    }
```

this is the URL:

http://tonto.eia.doe.gov/dnav/pet/xls/pet_pri_spt_s1_d.xls

Comment: I just tried it, and it works for me. What version of the excel interop assembly are you using?

Comment: @AviadP. Version 14.0.0

Comment: I tried it with 15.0.0.0 and with 14.0.0.0 and both worked without issue.... Something else in your setup is causing this.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dau-blog/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-applicationclass-to-interface-type-microsoft-office-interop-excel-application.aspx

Comment: @AviadP. I added all of the code, I don't know what I am missing

Comment: @stuartd I only have one version of Excel in the Registry

Comment: I used your code as is, still works for me. I have two versions, and I tested with both.

Comment: @AviadP. Any suggestions on what could be wrong for me?

Comment: Try this for a hint, might help http://help.turbolaw.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711886-Interop-error-when-creating-documents

Answer (score -2):

I presume the line with `var excel = new Application();` is the line where the exception is raised. From my experience in the matter, as I also tried to follow other advice found on the internet, the solution I accidentally found was to explicitly define the non use of 32 bit access mode for the interop dll.

For doing so in visual studio, I had to tick and then untick the box "Prefer 32-bit" in the build section of the project configuration, which added `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` in the .csproj file.